# How to get array of random integers of non-default type in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am generating a 2D array of random integers using numpy:

```
import numpy
arr = numpy.random.randint(16, size = (4, 4))
```

This is just an example. The array I am generating is actually enormous and of variable size. Since the numbers are always going to be from 0 to 16, I would like to save some space and have the array be of type `uint8`. I have tried the following

```
arr = numpy.random.randint(16, size = (width, height), dtype = numpy.uint8)
```

in an attempt to match the behavior of `zeros` and `ones`, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-103-966a510df1e7>", line 1, in <module>
    maze = numpy.random.randint(16, size = (width, height), dtype = numpy.uint8)

  File "mtrand.pyx", line 875, in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:9436)

TypeError: randint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

The docs for `randint()` do not mention anything about being able to set the type. How do I create a random array with a specific integer type? I am not tied to any one function, just a uniform distribution from 0 to 16 of type `uint8`.

Comment: As of NumPy 1.11 `randint` now has this missing `dtype=` option.

Comment: @Hannes. Thanks. I can no longer delete the question, so if you were to post an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The quickest way is to use the [`astype()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method:

```
x = np.random.randint(16, size=(4,4)).astype('uint8')
```

This works on any numpy array. But please note that by default it does not check that the casting is valid.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that [np.random.randint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) cannot specify `dtype`

```
import numpy as np

random_array = np.random.randint(0,16,(4,4))

[[13 13  9 12]
 [ 4  7  2 11]
 [13  3  5  1]
 [ 9 10  8 15]]

print(random_array.dtype)

>>int32

random_array = np.array(random_array,dtype=np.uint8)

print(random_array.dtype)

>>uint8
```